# PYTHON: Difference between if not i.find("Hey") and if i.find("Hey") == -1

Tags: python, string

I have the following code:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize

def main():
    directory = "\Surveys_I"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
       for i in dirs:
            if not i.find("Hey"):
                 print i
```

If I use the above code, I (counterintuitively) get a listing of all the files that contain the word Hey.  If I do

`if i.find("Hey") == -1` I get only the files that do not contain hey.

If I do:

`if i.find("Hey") == 1`, I don't get a single file.

What's going on?

Comment: Did you read the docs?: `Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.`

Comment: BTW the right approach to filter by names would be a regex, or in simple case like your just using the "in" operator ("Hey" in i).

Comment: You get a list of file names that *start* with "Hey" since the only result that not will be true with is 0, which is the start of the string. You either want `'Hey' in i` which'll be any substring, or `i.startswith('Hey')` if you really wanted the start...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.find` returns -1 when the sub-string is not found else it returns the index.

```
>>> 'abcd'.find('c')
2
>>> 'abcd'.find('e')
-1
 # returns 1 because the first matching sub-string starts at the index 1
>>> "aheyqwert".find('hey')
1
```

Help on `str.find`:

```
>>> help(str.find)
Help on method_descriptor:

find(...)
    S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Return -1 on failure.
```

Answer (score 4):

I addition to all other, correct answers:

If you'd only like get a boolean result on wether a string is contained (somewhere) within another, you can use the `in` operator:

```
if "hey" not in i:
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` points to the current directory name which is a string. When `Hey` is not found in the file's name `find` returns `-1`. Thats why you get all the files that do not contain `Hey`. `i.find("Hey") == 1` will only match the files whose name starts with any character followed by `Hey`. You may not have any such file. Thats why you don't get anything. You can fix it like this

To get all the files which have `Hey` in the names

```
for i in dirs:
    if "Hey" in i:
      ...
```

To get all the files which do **NOT** have `Hey` in the names

```
for i in dirs:
    if "Hey" not in i:
      ...
```